# installation problem using terminal

Tags: system-installation

```
narayan@josh:~$ sudo apt-get install root-system-bin

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 0):

if any software like:

1. Ubuntu software center
2. synaptic package manager
3. Software updater

or any other software manager(that you use to update or install) are running close them. then only you will not get this problem.

even after closing such software problem persist run this command:

`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

then run `sudo apt-get update` you should not get any error. now you can get back to the thing you were doing.